# Can't Create New Wordpress Database Table

Tags: wordpress

could someone please help me figure out why wordpress doesn't create the "my_notes" table when I activate my plugin.

```
<?php
/* NOTES */
function dashboard_my_notes()
{
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_notes';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(
            id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            date_notes DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
            status LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
            notes varchar(9999) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (id)
            );";
    dbDelta($sql);
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dashboard_my_notes' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the require_once in the line above dbDelta($sql). You are also putting the $table_name in as a string. If you are getting an error that upgrade.php cannot be found, try using  `ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php'` so there is an / before wp-admin.

**EDIT:** I did some changes to your sql statement, because your error told us to take a look at it. Please try if your database table is created.

```
<?php
/* NOTES */
function dashboard_my_notes()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'my_notes';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name."(
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            date_notes datetime NOT NULL,
            status longtext NOT NULL,
            notes text NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );";
    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dashboard_my_notes' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did tried your code,  but still doesn't work. after changing the code, I deactivated the plugin and re-activated it,  but still no luck !

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please set the debug in wp-config to true and check if there are any errors. What do you want to have the table for? maybe using sql is not needed and you can create a custom post type and add custom fields with ACF plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @rank,  here is the error I'm receiving :

Comment: Deprecated: get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.2.0! The home option is deprecated for the family of bloginfo() functions. Use the url option instead. in G:\MAMP\htdocs\www.mydemowebsite.dev\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4997

Comment: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTSwp_my_notes( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ' at line 1]
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSwp_my_notes( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date_notes DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, status LONGTEXT NOT NULL, notes varchar(9999) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )

Comment: The deprecated error is not connected. You have that problem somewhere else. But I edited my answer, can you try if it works for you?